# What is the story of Tulasi and her emergence from the Samudra Manthana?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, samudra-manthan, tulasi

There are two legends of Tulasi that are currently known, the one related to Jalandhara and the other related to Shankhachuda, both currently found in the Shiva Purana. In both the stories, Lord Vishnu has been portrayed as outraging the modesty of their respective wives, who then become the Tulasi plant.

However there is **another legend** that seems to be followed by Vaishnava Sampradayas, the brief of which is as follows: 
During the **Samudra Manthana**, Dhanvantari (incarnation of Lord Vishnu) comes with a Kalasha to distribute the Amrita. After the Devatas have been so given their share, Lord Vishnu sheds tears of happiness. These **tears mix with the Amrita and the Tulasi plant is born**. She married Lord Vishnu on Utthana Dvadashi (or Deva uthni Ekadashi as per the north).

**Questions**:

1. I would like to know the correct story of the origin of Tulasi from the Samudra Manthana by quoting from the relevant scripture.
2. Please mention how Tulasi got married to Lord Vishnu after Pradurbhava.
3. Are there any versions of the Bhagavatam that mention this story?
4. Are there any saints who have sung about this story?

It is not necessary to be same as the one mentioned above because that has not been sourced from scriptures.

---

**Rationale:**
 <sup>There are often some stories that denigrate gods like Lord Vishnu, Lord Shiva and Brahmaji. For example the story of Lord Shiva chopping of the head of his son vis-à-vis the actual version which the saints have sung of Shiva Parvati on becoming elephants involved in Ratikeli, produced Ganesha for the killing of Gajamukhasura.

Considering that Tulasi Vivaha comes not very far away from Lakshmi Pradurbhava (Diwali) during Samudra Manthana as well as the benevolent nature of Lord Vishnu, the link of Tulasi with Samudra manthana seems more likely.</sup>